# Count number of preemption for a running process in Linux

Tags: linux-kernel, scheduled-tasks, interrupt, sysfs, preemption

Is there any way to count preemption for specific PID from user space ? I am interested to measure how many times a process is preempted.

Comment: Can I use se.statistics.nr_wakeups from /proc/PID/sched ?